# Using Json Parser for parsing xml type webservices

Tags: android, xml, parsing, json

I have come to know that Json parser is fast over DOM & SAX parser. I also get information that Json parsing using for well formated Javascript type document.

My question is there .
Can we parse xml format Web Services using Json Parsing ?

If yes please suggest me some good example sources for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, JSON is a format, just like XML. A JSON document could look like:

```
{ 
  success: true, 
  result: ['item1', 'item2'] 
}
```

A corresponding XML could be describer as:

```
<return>
  <success>true</success>
  <result>
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
  </result>
</return>
```

You should read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to understand what JSON is and when to prefer using it in place of XML. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from the web service to the application using JSON format. And then you can use JSON parser